# How to use glyphicon in HTML helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this anchor element that displays glyphicon and some style:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-3d btn-xlg btn-reveal btn-brown">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    <span>REVEAL EXTRA LARGE</span>
</a>
```

In my project I use HTML helper to create anchor elements.

I have this html helper  to create anchor element:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "About", "Home", item, new { @class = "btn btn-3d btn-xlg btn-reveal btn-brown" })
```

But I don't know how to add   `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>` element to the HTML helper.

How can I define `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>` inside HTML helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Url.Action`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")" class="btn btn-3d btn-xlg btn-reveal btn-brown">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
  <span>REVEAL EXTRA LARGE</span>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for post.where do I put the Item ?

Comment: @Michael you can place it within the anchor tags with an @ before it. `@item.NAME`. Remove `<span>REVEAL EXTRA LARGE</span>` and place it there instead.